# Summarise data using .countBy

Tags: underscore.js

I'm trying to work out how I can summarise the following data using the [`_.countBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) method in [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/). I have the following data:

```js
var data =
[
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb8a58","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb983e","value":{"country":"Norway"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5ddfefe","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5fe29d7","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419751e8a14","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419753e20b6","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f34ad","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f3e17","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a506082f","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}},
    {"id":"9366afb036bf8b63c9f45379bbe29509","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}}
]
```

I would like to summarise it like this:

```js
{ 
    United_States: 3,
    Norway: 1,
    Hungary: 2,
    Germany: 2,
    United_Kingdom: 2
}
```

How would I pass this into the `_.countBy()` method provided by Underscore.js ?

Comment: As an aside: Try to accept a few more of the answers you have gotten. It's a nice habit to get into.

Comment: OK - So where do can I accept an answer. I don't see an option anywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var data =
[
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb8a58","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5bb983e","value":{"country":"Norway"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5ddfefe","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a5fe29d7","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419751e8a14","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419753e20b6","value":{"country":"Hungary"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f34ad","value":{"country":"United States"}},
    {"id":"b6ed02fb38d6506d7371c419755f3e17","value":{"country":"Germany"}},
    {"id":"338b79f07dfe8b3877b3aa41a506082f","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}},
    {"id":"9366afb036bf8b63c9f45379bbe29509","value":{"country":"United Kingdom"}}
];

var countData = _.countBy(data, function(obj){
    return obj.value.country.replace(" ", "_");
}); 

console.log(countData);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyDv7/1/

Comment: perfect that worked! Out of interest what does the obj.value.signature_algorithm.replace(" ", "_"); line do?

Comment: it's replacing the spaces in country name with underscores, so that the keys are valid. (although not exactly required :) )

Comment: What's the best way to then add the values from countData into a web page?

Answer (score 1):

"Clean js":

```js
var t = {};
for(var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++){
    t[data[i].value.country] = !t[data[i].value.country] ? 1 : t[data[i].value.country] + 1;
}
```

Result:

```
Germany 2
Hungary 2
Norway 1
United Kingdom 2
United States 3
```

Answer (score 0):

1 liner using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
var countData = data.reduce(function (a, x) {a[x.country] = (a[x.country] ? a[x.country] : 0) + 1; return a;}, {});
```